# TreeMaps using Holoviews

Tags: python, server, visualization, treemap, holoviews

I am using Holoviews for creating a visual dashboard and I want to create a Dynamic Tree Map within it. I tried finding documents, but I did not find any documentation of TreeMaps in the official Holoviews.
I then used Squarify library for plotting the TreeMaps but the Only Problem I am facing is that, I am not able to deploy these treemaps on server. When I start the server this Error message Pops up.

```
File "C:\Users\Nisarg.Bhatt\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site- 
packages\holoviews\plotting\util.py", line 236, in initialize_dynamic
dmaps = obj.traverse(lambda x: x, specs=[DynamicMap])
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'traverse'
```

CODE for TreeMap:

```
cmap = matplotlib.cm.Blues
mini=min(data["Quarter"])
maxi=max(data["Quarter"])
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=mini, vmax=maxi)
#colors = [cmap(norm(value)) for value in data]

data1=data[0:1]

labels = [(label) for label in zip(data.Quarter,data.Company)]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plots=squarify.plot(sizes=data["month"],label= labels, color= 
["red","blue","green"],alpha=.8)
new_plot= renderer.app(plots)
```

When this is executed, The TreeMaps are created in the Jupyter NoteBook.

QUERY:
1. Is there some other way of plotting TreeMap using just holoviews like hv.Curve or hv.Bars

2. How to solve this server issue.

Thanks in Advance.
Regards,
Nisarg

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower level library as bokeh (holoviews compatible) where you can plot rectangles as squarify does.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#plotting TreeMap using squarify.plot 

data = [8,3,4,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['nb_people'])
label=df.groupby(pd.cut(df["nb_people"], np.array([0,2,5,np.inf]),include_lowest=True,labels=['Group A','Group B','Group C'])).groups
squarify.plot(sizes=df['nb_people'], label=label, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

## squarify